# How to use PI as Radius Server

Tags: raspbian, dhcp

I am trying to use my Pi 3 (Raspbian)a as a RADIUS server for my ruckus access point. I am able to do it on standard ubuntu but I can't get it working on the Pi. The problem is the DHCP as I believe that these are different from Ubuntu and Raspbian. These are the settings that I use for Ubuntu:

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
    option routers              192.168.0.2;
    option subnet-mask          255.255.0.0;
    option broadcast-address    192.168.255.255;
    option domain-name-servers  192.168.0.2;
    range                       192.168.0.25 192.168.255.240;
    default-lease-time          1500;
    max-lease-time              1800;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where's the problem with dhcp. Basically the dhcp on the rpi has nothing in common with freeRADIUS (i think you're using freeRADIUS). If you want a static ip on the pi just create a rule on your router.
Maybe this guide will help you. https://www.globalknowledge.com/ca-en/resources/resource-library/white-paper/building-installing-and-configuring-a-radius-server/

Answer (score -1):

FYI ZeroShell is available for RPi, Radius is included, save yourself hours.

Comment: Jim, welcome to the RPi flavored corner of StackExchange. As is, your answer really doesn't offer a solution to fix the problem, just a sidestep.